# iOS 7 Custom push transitions to a transparent view controller, keeping from view controller's view visible beneath

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uimodalpresentationstyle

I'm creating a custom push transition (`UINavigationController`) from one view controller to a 
view controller who's view is transparent with blur.

I want the "from" view controller to remain visible beneath the newly pushed view controller.

I know I can achieve this effect if presenting the new view controller modally (using `modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom`), however is there a way to do this for a navigation controller?

The problem I am facing is that the from view controller's view is being removed from the container after the transition takes place.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a way for the system default to do this. If you want it to stay visible underneath, going with your own custom code seems best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using the new iOS 7 transitioning API's, you cannot keep the fromViewController.view under the toViewController.view as the containerView is managed privately once the animation has finished.

What you can do however is something like this...

```
UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];

UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

UIView *snapshotView = [fromViewController.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];

[toViewController.view addSubview:snapshotView];
[toViewController.view sendSubviewToBack:snapshotView];
```

I'm not too sure how well the last two lines will work (sending the snapshot to the back) but you could use a custom UIViewController subclass that can handle the snapshot and ensure that it is behind the rest of your content.

---

After re-reading.. I have a feeling you want to achieve some form of modal rather than a full screen presentation... My above solution would require that the toViewController is full screen... maybe you could then add a child view controller to the toViewController that actually houses the modal content?